# Cassandra or Tomcat Timesout

Tags: tomcat, cassandra-2.0

We are using Cassandra to store large amount of data. To fetch the data in web application using Tomcat we have few select * and select count(*). The data retrieval fails from the application which uses java code catching the timeout exception thrown by Cassandra. So, majorly it seems to be a Cassandra issue. Want to know if it could be Tomcat issue also? If its Cassandra issue would like to know if any solution for it.

Would like to know if any configuration parameter can be changed in cassandra yaml, so that the fix can be done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any comments guys? Its bit critical...

Comment: This is not a cassandra issue. I would say its either a problem with respect to your throttling or schema design. Share more details on your data model to know more. Your information is very incomplete. If you ask me, select * from any_table is a bad query , without conditions.